# Contentful SDK provider component

Tags: next.js, contentful

using  tag in nextjs showing an error in console like ---> "client.js:1 Cannot use App SDK outside of Contenful:

In order for the App SDK to function correctly, your app needs to be run in an iframe in the Contentful Web App, Compose or Launch."

How can i remove this error if not required. also other pages are not rendered while adding this tag in _app.js file

If removing the  remaining pages are renders correctly. while adding no rendering occurs.
want to avoid this console error

Comment: It seems like you are using the Contentful App SDK. To make sure I follow your question correctly, can you let me know if you are trying to make a website or a Contentful app? If it's a Contentful App, it will run inside Contentful and you can use our Next.js template to get started.